# RxJava as replacement for parallel calculating big factorials with StreamAPI

Tags: java, rx-java

I created a function that counts the time needed to calculate a factorial using many threads.
It is created using StreamAPI.

```
static Long streamParallelFactorial(int number) {

        long czasRozpoczecia = System.currentTimeMillis();
        IntStream.range(1, number).parallel().mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf).reduce(BigInteger.ONE,
                BigInteger::multiply);
        long czasZakonczenia = System.currentTimeMillis();

        return czasZakonczenia - czasRozpoczecia;
    }
```

Now I'm trying to do the same but using RxJava. During work, this monster came out.

```
static Long rxJavaParallelFactorial(int number) {
    long czasRozpoczecia = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Observable<Integer> vals = Observable.range(1,number);
    vals.flatMap(val -> Observable.just(val)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .scan(BigInteger.ONE, (big,cur) ->
            big.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(cur))));


    long czasZakonczenia = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return czasZakonczenia - czasRozpoczecia;
}
```

Someone would be nice and advise me what should I do to make it work?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with 'monster'? What exactly does not work?

Comment: @Heri Sometimes by "monster" I'm naming the code where I got lost. 
As for the problem with the working, I have no idea. Yesterday it simply stopped working and today it worked. Probably the environment must have blocked after my experiments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do parallel computation similary to Stream in RxJava 2+:

```java
Flowable.range(1, number)
.parallel()
.runOn(Schedulers.computation())
.map(BigInteger:valueOf)
.reduce(() -> BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger::multiply)
.reduce(BigInteger::multiply)
.subscribe();
```

Comment: Thanks for help but I have a question. 
What is this fragment for: `.reduce(BigInteger::multiply)
.subscribe(); `?

Comment: The parallel `reduce(Supplier, BiFunction)` in RxJava returns `ParallelFlowable` which has to be reduced once again to get the non-parallel single result.

Comment: Thaks now I understand.